# Yammer Rest API > Authentication based on server side script (php) without user interaction

Tags: yammer

My project has the requirement to access the yammer data using the given REST API using server side script(mainly PHP) and not involve a client side login using yammer's OAuth dialog.

I have gone through this document:

https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2

but this says, we requires user interaction.

What I wanted was can I generate a client_id and client_Secret to further generate access token to make API call out, but in all these processes I only use the authenticated users username and password in my server-side script.

Can anyone suggest a solution or is a client-side interaction required by design?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a user authorize the application at least once. This is just the nature of the OAuth implementation and you can't work around it. Having users go through the OAuth flow is considered a best practice.

If you have an OAuth token for a verified admin of Yammer, you can use [impersonation](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/impersonation) to [get tokens for end users without them interacting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askyammer/2016/11/04/preauthorizing-the-yammer-js-sdk/) with the OAuth flow.

Answer (score 0):

The below from Microsoft blogs might help you & added source at the end of answer.

1. Obtain a Verified Admin token for your application in one of the following 2 ways

   a. Create the app with a Verified Admin account and then in the app’s Basic Info page, click “Generate a developer token for this application.” Note that you’ll need to use this app’s info in the JS SDK and any subsequent calls.

   b.   Use the process outlined at https://developer.yammer.com/docs/test-token with a Verified Admin account to get an OAuth token for that VA account. Note that you must use the app info used to generate this token in all future steps.
2. Obtain the current user’s email address in the server-side script.
3. Using the VA token obtained in step 1 to authenticate, pass the user’s email address to our Get User by Email Address endpoint documented at https://developer.yammer.com/docs/usersby_emailjsonemailuserdomaincom, and then process the response
   a.  If the call to the API endpoint returns a 200 OK response, first check the “state” field to make sure the user is “active” and if so, store the “id” field that’s returned and go to step 4
   b.  If the call returns a 404 or a state other than “active,” direct the user to finish creating and activating their account however you like.
4. Once you have the user’s ID, you can pass it to our Impersonation endpoint to obtain a pre-authorized OAuth token for that user. This endpoint is documented at https://developer.yammer.com/docs/impersonation and must use the VA token obtained in step 1 to authorize the call, and the consumer_key of your JS SDK app.
5. You now have an OAuth token for the current user. When generating the code being passed to the browser, have the client side JS SDK code first call yam.platform.getLoginStatus and if there’s no active session and you have a token from step 4, pass that token to yam.platform.setAuthToken($tokenFromStep4, optional_callback_function_if_desired(response)).  If you don’t have a valid token, direct the user to finish setting up their Yammer account.
6. Continue making JS SDK calls as you normally would, without needing the user to authenticate.

**Source**: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askyammer/2016/11/04/preauthorizing-the-yammer-js-sdk/